# SQL Server 2008 OPENQUERY inside sp_executesql. Getting error incorrect syntax?

Tags: sql-server-2008, openquery

Code:

```
DECLARE @resultLast int, @siparisID nvarchar(21)
SET @siparisID = 2487

EXEC sp_executesql N'select * from OPENQUERY([MYSERVER],''Select  ( [MYDB].[dbo].[FN_SIPARIS_YUKLEME_TUTARI](@siparisID , 20 , 
                    [MYDB].[dbo].[FN_DATE_CONVERT_TO_DATE]( GETDATE()) , ''''BUY''''))'' )', @siparisID,
                N'@resultLast int output', @resultLast output;
```

I am trying to fetch data from linked server function. Also i need to send `@siparisID` parameter. I am getting incorrect syntax error. Help please...

Error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near '2487'.

Comment: Can you print the query, and execute it? Do you get the same error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've defined `@siparisID nvarchar(21)` - but you're setting it to a numerical datatype.

So **either** define it as a numeric datatype like `int` or `decimal(p,s)`:

```
DECLARE @siparisID INT
DECLARE @siparisID BIGINT
DECLARE @siparisID DECIMAL(16,2)
```

**or else** change the initialisation to

```
SET @siparisID = N'2487';
```

Comment: I've tried all.Still getting same error... Thanks anyway.